# Android - Spinner, onItemSelected(...) not being called

Tags: android, spinner

Here's the code:

```
import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStream;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.util.ArrayList;
import java.util.List;
import org.apache.http.HttpResponse;
import org.apache.http.client.HttpClient;
import org.apache.http.client.methods.HttpGet;
import org.apache.http.impl.client.DefaultHttpClient;
import org.apache.http.params.BasicHttpParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpConnectionParams;
import org.apache.http.params.HttpParams;
import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONObject;
import com.project.locationapp.model.Device;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.provider.Settings.Secure;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.Spinner;


public class SelectDevice extends Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener {

private Spinner deviceSpinner;
private List<Device> deviceList;
private ArrayAdapter<Device> deviceAdapter;

@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_select_device);
    deviceList = new ArrayList<Device>();


    try {
        deviceSpinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.select_device_spinner);
        deviceAdapter = new DeviceAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item, deviceList);
        deviceSpinner.setAdapter(deviceAdapter);
        deviceSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);

        DataAsyncTask loadDevices = new DataAsyncTask();
        loadDevices.execute(new String[] { WebServiceURL.WEB_SERVICE + WebServiceURL.DEVICES + WebServiceURL.ALL });




    } catch (Exception e){
        Log.e(TAG, e.getLocalizedMessage(), e);
    }
}

@Override
public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> a, View v, int position,
        long id) {

    Log.d(TAG, "called!");  
    Intent intent = new Intent(this, ViewTrips.class);
    intent.putExtra("device_id", deviceAdapter.getItem(position).getId());
    startActivity(intent);

}
}
```

DeviceAdapter class:

```
import java.util.List;
import com.project.locationapp.model.Device;
import android.content.Context;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;

public class DeviceAdapter extends ArrayAdapter<Device> {

public DeviceAdapter(Context context, int textViewResourceId,
        List<Device> objects) {
    super(context, textViewResourceId, objects);
}
}
```

Activity layout xml:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
tools:context=".SelectDevice" >


<TextView
    android:id="@+id/instructions_device_select"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
    android:text="@string/select_device_instructions"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="15dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="15dp" />

<Button
    android:id="@+id/start_service_button"
    android:layout_below="@id/instructions_device_select"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:onClick="thisDevice"
    android:text="@string/this_device"
    android:layout_marginTop="10dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="40dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="40dp" />

<Spinner
    android:id="@+id/select_device_spinner"
    android:layout_below="@id/start_service_button"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:prompt="@string/select_device"
    android:layout_marginTop="20dp"
    android:layout_marginLeft="5dp"
    android:drawSelectorOnTop = "true" />

</RelativeLayout>
```

I am waiting to get this working properly, then I am going to customise DeviceAdapter further.

The `Activity implements OnItemSelectedListener`, hence the override of `onItemSelected(...)`, which isn't being called at all. No errors in `LogCat`. `Spinner` is defined in the Activity's layout xml and displays and populates fine. Any advice to fix this would be great.

Thank you.

Comment: is onNothingSelected called ?

Comment: `catch (Exception e)` is a very bad practice. Can you remove that and try again.

Comment: I have removed try/catch, same problem, and onNothingSelected is not called either

Comment: I have the same problem. Have you found the solution?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

It might be the spinner layouts, I can see you didn't set a dropdown view for the adapter.
Could you try to initialize your spinner like this:

```
deviceAdapter = new DeviceAdapter(this, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item, deviceList);
deviceSpinner.setAdapter(deviceAdapter);
deviceAdapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
deviceSpinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
```

Comment: That has improved things a little (as in the view of the spinner when it is selected, however onItemSelected still isn't called

Comment: Have you overridden the ArrayAdapter's getView() method? If yes, you should only be using super.getView() for your testing to make sure that's not the cause. BTW - does onItemSelected get called when you use the default ArrayAdapter?

Comment: I haven't overriden the getView() method, and onItemSelected is not called when using the default ArrayAdapter (which was the main reason why I created my own).

Comment: Could you also update your code to show the imports and your layout XML? There doesn't seem to be any problems with your current code.

Comment: NP mate. Have you found the issue? I can only see one last possibility, maybe you should try initializing your ArrayAdapter and calling setAdapter on the Spinner after you load all the data into your List<Device> that you supply to your adapter. Once you modify the list data again, you should call adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() method so that the adapter will re-load the data from your list that will contain the latest data. Please let me know if these solve your problem, cheers

Comment: adapter.notifyDataSetChanged() worked a treat. Thank you, answer accepted.

Comment: @GTware Does the layout ResID have to be a textView ?

Comment: Spinner has no method setDropDownViewResource(). I think you mean to call that on the adapter.

Answer (score 0):

I was facing the same problem today. Then I realized I am testing on emulator. When I tested the same app it worked. I am posting this if someone is trying to get call back for spinner over emulator it did not work for me. you may also check the same. It works on real device