# onItemSelected Listner are not trigger with the long String array from database

Tags: java, android, android-spinner

UPDATE:

I found the problem, the problem may cause by get the adapter content from SQL requset. Now I post my getLockerList() code here now.

I tested the function with long string

```
"asdajdnajkdaadasdaajd najkdaadasdaajdnajkdaadasdaajdnajkdaadasdaajdnaj kdaadasdaajdnajkdaadasdasdas"
```

and it still could work perfectly, so now I guess the problem is come from when I got the data.

I set a spinner with arrayadapter. The content of adapter is come from MySQL request.

I got the data and create the adapter successfully, but when I try to show what item was selected by user, it show nothing after I click the item.

I've tried add some system print to find out the problem, finally I found that the problem is the listener not even call, no matter onItemSelected or onNothingSelected

I think I may find the problem now, my view list is stored different location which is very long String. I tried change the content of the adapter to "test" and it work perfectly. So now the problem is now can I display the long string?

Here is my code:

```
public class PlaceOrderActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener {
    private Spinner from_spinner;
    private ArrayList<String> locker_list = new ArrayList<String>();

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_order);
        getLockerList();

        from_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.from_spinner);
        from_spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,locker_list);
        from_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        from_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }

    private void getLockerList() {
         // Response received from the server
    Response.Listener<String> responseListener = new Response.Listener<String>() {
        @Override
        public void onResponse(String response) {
            try {
                JSONArray jsonResponse = new JSONArray(response);
                //JSONObject jsonObject = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(0);
                if (jsonResponse!=null) {
            //        System.out.println(jsonResponse);
                    for (int i=0;i< jsonResponse.length();i++)
                    {
                        JSONObject jsonObject = jsonResponse.getJSONObject(i);
                        String location = jsonObject.getString("location1")+" "+jsonObject.getString("location2")+" "+jsonObject.getString("location3");
                        locker_list.add(location);
                    }
                } else {
                }

            } catch (JSONException e) {
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    };
    Response.ErrorListener errorListener = new Response.ErrorListener() {
        @Override
        public void onErrorResponse(VolleyError error) {
            System.out.println(error);
        }
    };
    getLoockerLocationRequest request = new getLoockerLocationRequest(responseListener,errorListener);
    RequestQueue queue = Volley.newRequestQueue(PlaceOrderActivity.this);
    queue.add(request);
    }

    @Override
    public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
        System.out.println("selected item");
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),from_spinner.getSelectedItem().toString(),
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }


    @Override
    public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {
        System.out.println("nothing select");
        String no_selected_value = "Select the location";
        Toast.makeText(parent.getContext(),no_selected_value,
                Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show();
    }

}
```

Comment: The code seems good. Are you testing this on an emulator? This comment mentions that a similar problem occurred on an emulator but not on a real device. https://stackoverflow.com/a/52591103/490375

Comment: I think I may find the problem now, my view list is stored different location which is very long String. I tried change the content of the adapter to "test" and it work perfectly. So now the problem is now can I display the long string?

Comment: I'm not following. Is there some code missing from the piece that you posted?

Comment: Also, in onItemSelected you can change to Toast.makeText(this, locker_list.get(position), Toast.LENGTH_SHORT).show()

Comment: @MattRobertson Yes I haven't post the getLockerList() part. Now I posted it.

Comment: I think the problem may come from this function, after testing the program could work perfectly even the content of LockerList is very long and many. But if I set the content of lockerlist by the SQL request, the listener will not be trigger

Answer (score 0):

I solved the problem.

I don't know what is the concept of it. But if I add one extra item to the arraylist, no matter the item is "" (just blank/nothing inside) or "@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@@"

The program will became could run perfectly.

So I just add one `locker_list.add("");` before the adapter create.

```
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_place_order);
        locker_list.add("");
        getLockerList();
        from_spinner = (Spinner) findViewById(R.id.from_spinner);
        from_spinner.setVisibility(View.VISIBLE);
        ArrayAdapter adapter = new ArrayAdapter(this,android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item,locker_list);
        from_spinner.setAdapter(adapter);
        adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
        from_spinner.setOnItemSelectedListener(this);
    }
```